# How to Print RDDs in Scala

Tags: scala, printing, rdd, iterable

If I have a collection of RDDs that has the following form:

```
RDD[(ID, Iterable[(Var1,Var2)])]
```

So the data looks like this:

```
RDD[("ID1",[(1,3),(1,12),(1,6)])],
RDD[("ID2",[(2,5),(2,7)])]
```

What is the best way to print out the values?

*Edited as per @Luis, If I just do:

```
rdd.collect().foreach(println)
```

The program errors out with the following:

```
19/02/02 14:04:55 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 2)
java.lang.ClassCastException
19/02/02 14:04:55 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 2, localhost, executor driver): java.lang.ClassCastException

19/02/02 14:04:55 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 2.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
19/02/02 14:04:55 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 2.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool
19/02/02 14:04:55 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Cancelling stage 2
19/02/02 14:04:55 INFO DAGScheduler: ShuffleMapStage 2 (map at StackOverflow.scala:85) failed in 0.093 s due to Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 2.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 2, localhost, executor driver)
: java.lang.ClassCastException

Driver stacktrace:
19/02/02 14:04:55 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 1 failed: collect at StackOverflowSuite.scala:54, took 0.162394 s
```

Comment: `RDDs` are distributed by nature, you cannot print them on your main, in general terms, because they are supposed to live on many machines. You can always `collect` them _(if you are sure that would not blow your memory)_ to get a **local collection** you can print.

Comment: @user2864740 I have added in more error information and added `collect()`.

Comment: As you can see, the failure is a `java.lang.ClassCastException`, remember that **Spark** is lazy, having an `RDD[X]` does not mean that all the work until there will be fine... `collect` is an _Action_ that means that it will execute all the compute graph to get your results, and in that process it is failing. - We cannot help you with that error without seeing the code that cause it, you may try doing debug steps on every transformation to see how your program behaves.